# Change primary display through command line

Tags: display

Is it possible to change the primary screen for a Mac through command line?

The traditional way of doing this is from System Preferences > Displays and dragging the white menu bar on the top, between screens.

I have different setups at home and work and sometimes I need the primary display to be different. Rather than having to change this by dragging/dropping as explained above, I would like to run a script through a program like Alfred/QuickSilver and then just toggle/switch my primary displays.

If i could do this through command line, it would be awesome. There is this program called cscreen that allows me to do this, [but it only runs on PowerMacs](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?p=315509).

Comment: If no one has an easy answer, you might need to run `fs_usage` and track which preference file changes to record the choice of screen to host the menu bar. Once you've captured a version of that file for each layout, you could easily script that as a shell script. Also, try comparing the files in case it's just a trivial edit and the preference isn't somehow embedded in a data structure or otherwise not easily editable by a shell script.

Answer (score 1):

[cscreen](http://www.pyehouse.com/cscreen/) actually runs on Intel-based Mac as well. You should be able to change primary display through it.